# Add schema.org article - problem with LOGO

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, ldjson

I tried to add a schema.org `article` on a page but it is not validated by Google, maybe the problem is with the logo ?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
     "@context": "https://schema.org",
     "@type": "Article",
     "author": "Organization",
     "name": "mywebsite",
     "headline": "Pericolosità - DEFINIZIONE",
     "image": [
         "https://www.example.com/a.jpg"
     ],
     "datePublished": "2021-04-09T04:00:00+00:00",
     "dateModified": "2021-04-09T04:00:00+00:00",
     "mainEntityOfPage": "https://www.example.com/article",
     "publisher":{
         "@type": "Organization",
         "name":"mywebsite",
         "url": "https://www.example.com/logo.jpg",
         "logo": {
             "@type": "imageObject",
             "url": "https://www.example.com/logo.jpg"
         }
      }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the publisher, you specified the URL property for the logo:

```
"publisher":{
     "@type": "Organization",
     "name":"mywebsite",
     "url": "https://www.example.com/logo.jpg",
     "logo": {
         "@type": "imageObject",
         "url": "https://www.example.com/logo.jpg"
     }
  }
```

However, it requires the URL of the publisher's website but not the logo.

In addition, the problem with a particular logo may be due to the wrong size or format, which you do not report. So check to see how your logo matches **[Google's Guidelines for Logo](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/logo)**.

Comment: but i'm the publisher, i'm admin of my website. So what URL can i add?  the homepage ?

Comment: The content page of which represents the publisher's organization.